# Magento2 : recaptcha v2 not working

Tags: magento2.2, google-recaptcha

Iam using magento2.2. I added "iam not robot" recaptcha v2 from admin by default configuration but it is getting error like "This site key is not enabled". Why default configuration not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the domain you are using to the recaptcha account setup on Google?

See the example below where I've added `example.com`
[image: ReCaptcha setup]